# Azure DevOps pipeline release Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a\**\*.zip angular

Tags: node.js, angularjs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have an Angular project in Azure DevOps repository and it gets built OK using the DevOps build pipeline. However, the release over that builds always fails with this error:

**Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a_SocialMetric
Check if the package mentioned in the task is published as an artifact in the build or a previous stage and downloaded in the current job.**

Answer (score 0):

The path you provided seems not to have '_work' folder and 'r1' and 'a' folders have replaced positions. Artifacts are downloaded to folder like

D:\myAgentFolderName\_work\r1\a\(...)

You can check your artifacts path by checking predefined variable
$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batchace

Node.js and Angular tags seems not to be necessary for this question